# Пример программного управления транзакциями в Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, transaction

Ищу пример реализации программного управления транзакциями в Spring Boot и Spring Data JPA. Везде только для Spring framework. И в документации по Spring Boot ничего по этому поводу нормального нет.

Нужно ли настраивать бины в Spring Boot:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource"), @Bean(name = "sessionFactory"), @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
```

и другие как это делается в Spring Framework, или же в Spring Boot достаточно аннотации
`@EnableTransactionManagement`?

Comment: + hibernate и БД MySQL

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду, говоря программного(!) управления транзакциями? Вешать аннотации Transactional или через энтити менеджер начинать и заканчивать транзакции вручную ?

Comment: через энтити менеджер управлять транзакциями

Answer (score 1):

Да, бины надо настраивать, иначе они будут сконфигурированы по своему. Но, для того, чтобы конфигурация началась надо ставить `@EnableTransactionManagement` и добавить в pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Пример можно взять [здесь](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/#use-maven). В примере используется аннотация `@Transactional` для демарковки транзакций.

Если есть необходимость использовать транзакции программатично, то нужно читать [тут](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-programmatic).

Comment: там идет работа с транзакциями внутри jpa, а что если я хочу использовать в методе программно транзакцию есть ли такой пример для spring boot? спасибо

Comment: @OlegIvanovskij Обновил.

Comment: Т.е. для spring boot примера получается в доках спринга нет? или где-нибудь еще?

Comment: потому что я уже много доков просмотрел спринга и не нашел

Comment: Делайте транзакции как в спринге а  спринг бут это лишь оболочка для спринга.

Comment: я сделал spring boot приложение, и просто повесил аннотацию на метод в классе сервиса @Transactional и всё работает, очень странно, причем работает правильно как и должно работать по документациям.

Comment: Видите как программатично получается у спринга работа с транзакциями.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы программно хотите управлять транзакциями, все что нужно сделать:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(enableDefaultTransactions = false)
public class SpringBootApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Далее просто навешивайте аннотацию @Transactional на методы ваших сервисов. (Никакого отличия от спринга без бута).

Если интересно как спринг бут конфигурирует transaction manager, hibernate и containerFBean, то можете посмотреть в **[этом](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration.java)** классе.

Comment: @EnableJpaRepositories(enableDefaultTransactions = false) - получается эта аннотация отключит все стандартные транзакции которые делает под капотом jpa?

Comment: @OlegIvanovskij  да, она отключит транзакции, которые используются интерфейсами Spring Data. Вам придется самому управлять транзакциями (через TransactionTemplate или аннотациями)

Comment: хм, тогда мне такой подход не подойдет и придется использовать декларативные транзакции, осталось только разобраться как их настраивать... так как я вчера сделал тестовое приложение spring boot и просто повесил аннотацию на метод в классе сервиса @Transactional и всё работает, очень странно, причем работает правильно как и должно работать по документациям springa

Comment: но если посмотреть как спринг бут конфигурирует transaction manager, hibernate и containerFBean, то можно увидеть, что скорее всего бины не нужно самому конфингурировать как в spring, а просто вешать @Transactional

Comment: @OlegIvanovskij суть моего ответа - как раз в этом. Если убрать дефолтные транзакции, то вы управляете ими через Transactional, как  в обычном спринге. Если не убираете, тогда нет необходимости использовать Transactional, потому что спринг дата сделает это за вас.

Comment: не совсем, если у меня в одном методе будет две операции сохранения например в бд, то мне нужно принудительно аннотировать метод @Transactional, чтобы транзакция выполнялась для двух операций как одна операция. в целом спасибо за класс с примером он прояснил хоть что-то

Comment: @OlegIvanovskij таким образом вы просто оверайдите поведение. А если у вас в методе 1 запись, то Transactional можно не использовать.

Comment: @OlegIvanovskij Короче говоря : enableDefaultTransactional добавит transaction begin/end в прокси, которые создаст спринг дата, отсюда у вас и 2 транзакции в 1 методе.

Comment: да всё верно, получается так